# PHP - search_array

Tags: php

I have one Multiple Array...

File "user.php" --> imports the data from the "zebra_output_input.json" File and outputs a Zebra-Style Table with a list of all users and projects. One user can have more then one project, so it can have more then one line of text in the table (more then one array).

I have a sessions assigned to different users ("$loggedUser = $_SESSION["user"];") after the successful login, so I should now be able to filter the output so that only the data (lines of text - array) that matters for each user shows up.

Something like: first two lines (Arrays 0 and 1) gets User1, second one goes to the User2 ... last two ones for User5.

There is no databank involved in preprocessing the data. Right now, every user has its own JSON file (like it would be if the databank would give me the results). That's a bit impractical in this case since there is a project list for all users + one extra list for each and every user.

Some way to do it?

1. Array:

```js
[{"Nr":"146","Kuerzel":"COUVERTIC","Projekttitel":"Arbeiten Output Management","Kunde":"COUVERTI","User":"User1"},{"Nr":"147","Kuerzel":"CEBILL","Projekttitel":"Vom PDF zur eRechnung","Kunde":"COUVERTI","User":"User1"},{"Nr":"157","Kuerzel":"KALAIDOS","Projekttitel":"Kurse bei Kalaidos","Kunde":"KFS","User":"User2"},{"Nr":"158","Kuerzel":"LPCH","Projekttitel":"Einsatz Harald M\u00fcller als Syst. Eng & W'Inform","Kunde":"LP","User":"User3"},{"Nr":"152","Kuerzel":"INFONOVA","Projekttitel":"PrintMachine","Kunde":"NEOPOST","User":"User4"},{"Nr":"1","Kuerzel":"AB","Projekttitel":"Allgemeine B\u00fcroarbeiten","Kunde":"INTERN","User":"User5"},{"Nr":"2","Kuerzel":"KA","Projekttitel":"Krank, Arzt","Kunde":"INTERN","User":"User5"}]
```

2. Processing file:

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>unbenannt</title>
 <style>
   table {background-color:white;}
   th {background-color:#58ACFA;}
   .cssEven {background-color:#E0ECF8;}
   .cssOdd  {background-color:#b8d3ef;}
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>

 <br><br>

   <h1><img class="fehleranimation" src="../img/key36.png"> Willkommen im geschützten Bereich '<?= $_SESSION["user"]?>'.</h1>

 <br><br>

  <table>
   <tr>
    <th width="50" align="right">Nr</th>
    <th width="150" align="left">Kuerzel</th>
    <th width="350" align="left">Projekttitel</th>
    <th width="150" align="left">Kunde</th>
    <th width="100" align="center">User</th>
   </tr>

   <?php

   $loggedUser = $_SESSION["user"];
   //$userfile = file_get_contents('projekte_'.$loggedUser.'.json');
   $userfile = file_get_contents('zebra_output_input.json');
   $jsonarray = json_decode($userfile);
   $index = count($jsonarray);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++) {
     $style = "cssOdd";
     //$_SESSION['user'] = $jsonarray[$i]->User;
     if ($i % 2 != 0) {
      $style = "cssEven";
     }
     if($loggedUser === $jsonarray[$i]->User) {
      echo
      '<tr class="'.$style.'">
       <td align="right">'. $jsonarray[$i]->Nr.' </td>
       <td>'. $jsonarray[$i]->Kuerzel.' </td>
       <td>'. $jsonarray[$i]->Projekttitel.' </td>
       <td>'. $jsonarray[$i]->Kunde.'</td>
       <td align="center">'. $jsonarray[$i]->User.' </td>
      </tr>';
     }
    }
   ?>

  </table>

 </body>

</html>
```

*Edited*

Comment: Please narrow it down to a small code sample as best you can (*"I've got this array: <sample>, and I want to do this: <sample/explanation>"*). We shouldn't need to follow a multi-page process to answer a simple question about some array operation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Willhelmine. Please see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The way the question is written right now makes it hard to understand exactly what your problem is. Try narrowing it down to a specific issue. Don't ask one question for several issues. Make your code samples as small as possible, because code takes time to read and understand. Finally, even though your intentions are nice the question is a bit "chatty" - please leave out the thank you's and intro. The goal is for questions to be helpful to everyone with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you to the editor for removing that...

Comment: @ André Laszlo & deceze: Please excuse... didn't now which part might be relevant and was thinking "the more, the better". That way one can copy & paste, let it run in Xampp and you have what I have. One more time -Soory! :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an identifier.

You need to match the $_SESSION['user'] with the corresponding

$jsonarray[$i]->User.

Hope it helps!

```
$loggedUser = $_SESSION["user"];
$userfile   = file_get_contents('projekte_'.$loggedUser.'.json');
$jsonarray  = json_decode($userfile);
$index      = count($jsonarray);

for ($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++) {
    $style = "cssOdd";
    if ($i % 2 != 0) {
        $style = "cssEven";
    }

    if($loggedUser === $jsonarray[$i]->User) {
        echo
            '<tr class="' . $style . '">
            <td align="center">' . $jsonarray[$i]->User . ' </td>
            <td align="right">' . $jsonarray[$i]->Nr . ' </td>
            <td>' . $jsonarray[$i]->Kuerzel . ' </td>
            <td>' . $jsonarray[$i]->Projekttitel . ' </td>
            <td>' . $jsonarray[$i]->Kunde . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Even if I add "$_SESSION['user'] = $jsonarray[$i]->User;" on the place marked with `enter code here`, I still get complete JSON file / Table. With other words, User1 gets all the projects for User1 ~ User5 instead only first two lines (=Arrays from the JSON file).

Comment: the 'enter code here' didn't belong there, I edited the answer. the if statement should wrap around your echo. Also what's in $_SESSION['user'] ? The $jsonarray[$i]->User or the $jsonarray[$i]->Nr. ? You need a matching value.

Comment: Edited like that returns only empty Table instead of first to arrays for User1, third for the User2 ... last two for the User5.

Comment: I process the login in "login.php" file. If the username and password are matching (= O.K.), then I pass: "session_start();" "$_SESSION["user"] = $user;" and "header("Location: user.php");" over to "user.php" that you can see on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Some points to consider.

1. If you are fetching the data from the database do the `filtering` there and **no need to** *fetch all the data and then filter in `php`*.
2. If you are reading this array from some other source, like a file maybe, then just loop through each one of the array and check if the user matches the user stored in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: No database. Just reading the local JSON file named "zebra_output_input.json" consisting of 7 arrays (multi-array) and exactly "just loop through each one of the array and check if the user matches the user stored in $_SESSION" ist the thing that i can't get working - no matter which user logs in, they allways see all the data.